# What are the shape clipping limitations with Codename One?

Tags: codenameone

I'm trying again to build a frosted glass effect for list entries.

Testing this I got an exception trying to shrink the shape using `com.codename1.ui.geom.GeneralPath.intersect(Rectangle)`. Then I used `com.codename1.ui.Graphics.clipRect(int, int, int, int)` and it worked well in the simulator.

But on my iPhone 5S I get the exception again:

[image]

What restrictions should be observed when using shape clipping?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently this is a limitation in the iOS port (and possibly other platforms).  The iOS port uses the clipping and shape intersection functionality from the GeneralPath class.  So far I've only implemented intersection of a polygon with a rectangle.  Other combinations aren't supported yet.

Please file an issue in the issue tracker.

In the mean time, the workaround would be to convert your shape to a polygon (e.g. interpolate all of your bezier curves with line segments).

Comment: See [#2023 - Shape clipping - Runtime exception on certain platforms](https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/2023)

Comment: For now I will do the clipping by painting into an image. Hopefully there will be no further limitations with that.

Comment: [#2026 - Shape clipping throws NullPointerException](https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/2026)

Comment: I found another issue: [#2027- Shape clipping not working on Image.createImage(width, height).getGraphics()](https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/2027)

Answer (score 0):

This is thrown [here](https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/blob/1ac7c6192cae151cb1665888d4a16175d56ef892/CodenameOne/src/com/codename1/ui/geom/GeneralPath.java#L2015). From my understanding of the logic there are segmentation rules that don't make sense in an unclosed shape and shouldn't be used when constructing an open (or potentially open) path.

Comment: In the simulator I can call `com.codename1.ui.Graphics.setClip(Shape)` followed by `com.codename1.ui.Graphics.clipRect(int, int, int, int)` even if the shape is a GeneralPath instance containing curves. This fails on IOS.

Comment: There might be edge cases although as far as I can tell this exception is thrown from Java code not from native code so failures should be reproducible. It might relate to device resolution differences that cause the creation of a slightly different shape.

Comment: I do not believe that different resolutions are responsible for this behavior. It works fine in the simulator with various skins in various resolutions and it fails on my iPhone 5S and on my iPad Air 2.

Comment: I don't see how that would happen but I'll ask